# Django, how public links on Facebook?

Tags: django, facebook

i did it with twitter, update status, but now, i need to do with facebook, just i want to public a "link" on "Facebook Pages", i would like to send my title post from my django app to my Facebook Pages....

any tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm understanding that you want to update your Facebook status via an action that happens within your Django application.

"There's a Module For That™"  (man the python community is awesome)  This isn't Django specific, but check out [PyFacebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PythonPyFacebookTutorial).  It's a python interface to the Facebook API.